# Linear transformation of polynomials, given transformation output

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, transformation

I need to find a transformation of a polynomial, given the output of other polynomial calculations:

If $T : P_1 \mapsto P_2$ is a linear transformation such that,
$$
T(1 + 5x) = 1 - 2x \quad\text{and}\quad T(3 + 14x) = -2 - 4x
$$
Then $T(3 - 2x) =$ ?

Please explain this as simple as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you can write $$(3 - 2x) = a (1 + 5x) + b (3 + 14x)$$

then the linearity of $T$ implies that you can write

\begin{align*}
T(3 - 2x) &= a T(1 + 5x) + b T(3 + 14x) \\
&= a(1 - 2x) + b(-2 - 4x) \\&
= (a - 2b) + (-2a - 4b)x
\end{align*}

So can you determine $a$ and $b$?

Comment: I've been trying to make sense of it for the past ~20 minutes, I just can't seem to see how to continue. I understand everything up to:
... = (a-2b)+(-2a-4b)x
It seems I just can't understand math, while anything related to computer science comes easy. Is there a specific way I should think of this as?

Comment: @MayBee It's just a linear equation, whose coefficients involve $a$'s and $b$'s. So just combine the constant terms (giving a term $a$ from the first bit and a term $-2b$ from the second), and then combine the terms with an $x$ in them.

Comment: What I meant to say was I understand everything up to and including the last part, except I can't continue. I don't know what comes next, or like you said, how to find a and b. I tried using the first part (a-2b) as a vector and (-2a-4b) as another and augmenting it with {{3}, {-2}}, so I had:
v1 = {1, -2}, v2 = {-2, -4}, and a matrix A = {v1, v2}, then I augmented it with b such that b = {3,-2}
=> [A | b] and row reducing to find x such that x = {a, b} but this is wrong, I can't connect the dots apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Write $3-2x$ in terms of $1+5x$ and $3+14x$. Specifically $3-2x = -52(1+5x) + 11(3+14x)$.

Now use linearity of $T$ to figure out what $T(-52(1+5x) + 11(3+14x))$ is.

Note that the $(-52,11)^T$ came from solving
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 5 \\ 3 & 14 \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -2\end{bmatrix}$.

**To elaborate**:
Since $3-2x = -52(1+5x) + 11(3+14x)$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
T(3-2x) &=& T(-52(1+5x) + 11(3+14x)) \\
&=&  -52 (  T(1+5x) ) + 11 ( T(3+14x) ) \\
&=& -52(1-2x) + 11(-2-4x) \\
&=& -74+60x
\end{eqnarray}